# How to include the subsection numbers when using the algorithm2e package?

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I am using the package `algorithm2e`. By default, the numbers of the algorithms either related to part, chapter or section.
what I want is to get the following numbering for the algorithms:

> Algorithm section.subsection.algorithm

How to get this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting

Answer (score 7):

You may try

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{algocf}{section}
\counterwithin*{algocf}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{algocf}}
```

after having loaded **algorithm2e** (with the default `algosection` option).

The first command frees the counter from its bound to `section`, the second one binds the counter to `subsection`. The third line finally redefines the format for  representing the counter's value, using the numbers you want.

Comment: Thank you. I have tested the lines you sent me. The problem now is the following:

Comment: Thank you Egreg. The problem now is the following: when I ran the .tex file, I got the numbering like: Algorithm 2.2.1.2 which suppose to refer to section 2 subsection 1 and algorithm 2... Why the first 2? why it is 4 places. The interesting thing is I have tried almost every thing: I removed "algosection" option. I removed "\counterwithout" I removed "\counterwithin", I removed * from the second one and I add * to the first one. I also tried to change redefinition of "thealgocf". the thing is  numbering of the algorithm does not response to the changing that I am making